# Is it possible to copy/paste text inside oculus quest with native controllers?

Tags: android, firefox, virtual-reality, sideloading, oculusquest

It seems oculus quest is lacking a native implementation of copy/pasting text (at least with oculus controllers).

Clipboard is part of android core functionality. Did anyone implemented a "hack" to sideload android package that will allow copy/paste inside oculus quest like on any regular android device? Maybe someone has a VR browser for quest with copy paste functionality (I've tried firefox reality where you can only select the text but can't copy/paste it with oculus controls).